# Avoiding loops over 2D array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, image, loops, numpy

I am stuck trying to figure out how to avoid doing 2 loops while doing some analysis on an image. Its a square image (same dimension in the x and y). The current way its set up its that for each pixel, in the array "stars", the first coordinate is the x position, the second coordinate is the y position, and the third coordinate is the brightness of the pixel. I know there must be a far far superior way to set this up but every thing I try just works when i=j (giving me essentially only the diagonal of this matrix). How do I do this better?!

```
def firstmoment(stars,bins):
    xsum=0.0
    ysum=0.0
    itot=0.0
    for i in range(0, bins):
        for j in range(0, bins):
            xsum=xsum+stars[i][j][0]*stars[i][j][2]
            ysum=ysum+stars[i][j][1]*stars[i][j][2]
            itot=itot+stars[i][j][2]
    x0=xsum/itot
    y0=ysum/itot
    return x0, y0, itot
```

Comment: Please provide some representative example data for `stars` and `bins`.  See how to make a [mcve].  Also include expected output for the sample data you provide (that way answers can verify their correctness).

Comment: To be honest I'm not that sure you can reduce the 2 loops to one loop only, unless there are very particular conditions [e.g. working on the diagonal, like you already said]. The image is a 2D territory and then in general you can't escape running a loop along its 2 dimensions. In the same way as you can't generally skip two loops when working on a square matrix

Comment: looks like `xsum=np.sum(stars[:,:,0]*stars[:,:,2])`. etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just focus on the `x` part, ignoring `y` because it works the same way.

```
def firstmoment(stars, bins):
    xsum = 0.0
    itot = 0.0
    for i in range(bins):
        for j in range(bins):
            xsum += stars[i][j][0] * stars[i][j][2]
            itot += stars[i][j][2]
    x0 = xsum / itot
    return x0, itot
```

`stars` is a 3D array indexed as `[x, y, luminance]`.  At the end, `itot` is the sum of the luminance values, which is trivially `stars[:bins,:bins,2].sum()`.  Using a similar transformation for `xsum`, we get:

```
def firstmoment(stars, bins):
    xsum = (stars[:bins,:bins,0] * stars[:bins,:bins,2]).sum()
    itot = stars[:bins,:bins,2].sum()
    x0 = xsum / itot
    return x0, itot
```

Comment: thank you for helping me get rid of the loops! this works like a charm and is definitely faster :)